How may Unicode-math access the power set symbol suggested in an earlier question?
Confer question: How may unicode-math access the following common power set symbol?, which asks for a standard, or prevalent power set symbol under unicode-math.
As I want to distinguish between power sets and potency sets, I want as well the rather nice symbol, suggested
in the answer to: Symbol similar to \mathcal{P}
by Mico, for the distinct notion of potency set.
How may one have nice access to that symbol under unicode-math?
Edit: The accepted answer to How may unicode-math access the following common power set symbol? is by setting another math font - \setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal,bfcal}] - for a subrange. But I do not know of a math font which may serve the purpose, or what its range should be^.
^ The math font needed was Euler-math, and the range which was preferable to use was symscr. Confer the answer below.

It's hard to figure out what you're asking without ten minutes flipping between this question and the linked one.  Could you edit this so that it stands on its own?  Referring to the other one is fine, but making us go through two other questions to figure this one out isn't going to work.

this question seems identical to your previous one, you are shown there how to select two different P, after that it is just a matter of selecting fonts, and the font catalogue or other sources will let you choose. You reference Mico's answer but don't say which P you want there "potency" is not mentioned.

@DavidCarlisle The answer to the former invokes a package - \usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}, and the latter is by setting another math font \setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal,bfcal}] for a subrange. I have tried the latter kind of strategy for the former problem, but without success.

you do not say which of the P from the other question you want,  or why you are specifically asking for 8 bit fonts to be accessed using unicode-math which is designed to replace all tex's 8 bit math font handling by OpenType math layout.  Sorry I would not be able to guess an answer here, look at for example texdoc unimath-symbols and pick a P that you like.

egreg shows also here how to get both styles of script using unicode-math  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120073/1090  there is really nothing else to be said other than picking a font you like.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks! I started with Unicode-math only this week, and there has been a lot of exhausting ransition work.

but why use unicode math and then ask so many questions on how to avoid everything it does and use the same fonts as classic tex, why not simply not use unicode math??? The sensible answer to "how to get the P in mico's posting"  is "use the code Mico showed" why the extra constraint given no real justification of doing it using a specific package that is designed to do something else?

@DavidCarlisle There are bound to be transitional issues when one starts something new.

@DavidCarlisle I had no "extra constraint given no real justification of doing it using a specific package". I rather wanted to do it in a manner akin to question, and egreg's answer to, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723778/how-may-unicode-math-access-the-following-common-power-set-symbol/723785?noredirect=1#comment1800950_723785.

well yes because as far as I can tell this question is identical to that one. Maybe it isn't but I see no difference. The range is given as specified by Unicode so it's just a matter of changing the font and using one you like,

The question intended to ask for the symbol Mico offered, to an earlier question, by means of a package. But Mico's symbol should be offered by using such techniques as egreg made use of in his answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723778/how-may-unicode-math-access-the-following-common-power-set-symbol. Mico's answer was
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{P} \quad \mathcal{P}$
\end{document}


So the P I look for is the upright Eulerscript P on page 8 here: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf. I tried the equivalent of egreg's answer with mathalpha and Euler as font names, but that did not work.

Below is a way to obtain the P's I was looking for. The answer combines elements from earlier answers, to partial questions, by Mico and egreg.
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\CMcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\CMbfcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\symscr]{Euler-Math.otf}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[range={cal, bfcal}]

\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}[range=]

\newcommand{\pow}{\CMcal{P}}

\newcommand{\pot}{\mathscr{P}}


\begin{document}

 $\pot \ \& \ \pow$

\end{document}



